# Проставление множества реакций под сообщением discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, бот, discord.py

Задержка в расстановке реакций

Боту нужно проставить 10 реакций под сообщение. Когда я использую

```
await msg.add_reaction('1️⃣')
await msg.add_reaction('2️⃣')
await msg.add_reaction('3️⃣')
await msg.add_reaction('4️⃣')
await msg.add_reaction('5️⃣')
await msg.add_reaction('6️⃣')
await msg.add_reaction('7️⃣')
await msg.add_reaction('8️⃣')
await msg.add_reaction('9️⃣')
await msg.add_reaction('')
```

Бот справляется с этим, однако с заметной задержкой (поставил единичку, прошла секунда, поставил двоечку и т.д.)
Как это исправить?